# Setting attributes by looping through object keys and values

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object that I loop through with Object.keys and for each of those keys I want to set attributes that are also defined in that Object as an array of a key.

My code loops through the objects, sets the attribute but the for loop only sets the last index as an attribute so that all elements have the same attribute.

```
const headerElements = [
  {
    pageLinksHeader: document.createElement("div"),
    class: "page-links-header",
  },
  {
    companyNameHeader: document.createElement("div"),
    class: "company-name-header",
  },
  {
    mainPageLink: document.createElement("a"),
    text: "example",
    link: "../../index.html",
  },
  {
    webPagesHeader: document.createElement("div"),
    class: "webpages-header",
  },
  {
    webPageTarieven: document.createElement("a"),
    webPageReserveren: document.createElement("a"),
    webPageContact: document.createElement("a"),
  },
  {
    webPagesLinks: [
      "../../tarieven.html",
      "../../reseveren.html",
      "./contact.html",
    ],
    webPagesText: ["Tarieven", "Reserveren", "Contact"],
  },
];

Object.keys(headerElements[4]).forEach((attr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    headerElements[4][attr].setAttribute(
      "href",
      headerElements[5].webPagesLinks[i]
    );
  }
});
```

I tried different loops like I a do while where I thought it would take the first index at least but all just set the last index (i=3) as the attribute.

As far as I understand the for loop, loops through at the first key and then the forEach function goes on and sets all element attributes to i=3 because the for loop does not exit or return anything when i=1.

I want to understand if I can make it loop through correctly or if it isn't possible.

Comment: do you have some data of `headerElements`?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to provide a working example of the problem.

Comment: In order to know what you are doing we will need as much info as possible. What is contained inside `headerElements` for example? It seems very aribitray to use `headerElements[4]` and then later `headerElements[5]` etc... Very confusiong

Comment: I have added the headerElement, I defined the element and attributes in different object that I access with the place in the array as you can see

Comment: You're setting the `href` on the same element 3 times. So therefore it will only ever contain the value set in the last loop. What output are you expecting to see?

Comment: I was expecting that each of the elements under the webPagesLinks array would be set as the href value in order but only 'contact.html' is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because within the `forEach()` over `Object.keys()` you are setting the `href` of the *same* element 3 times due to the `for` loop. Therefore each one will only ever contain the last value in the `webPagesLinks` array.

To do what you require, remove the inner `for` loop and use the `index` from `forEach()` to set the `href` instead. You can use the same pattern to also set the text for each link too:

```
Object.keys(headerElements[4]).forEach((attr, i) => {
  headerElements[4][attr].setAttribute("href", headerElements[5].webPagesLinks[i]);
  headerElements[4][attr].textContent = headerElements[5].webPagesText[i];
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const headerElements = [{pageLinksHeader:document.createElement("div"),class:"page-links-header"},{companyNameHeader:document.createElement("div"),class:"company-name-header"},{mainPageLink:document.createElement("a"),text:"example",link:"../../index.html"},{webPagesHeader:document.createElement("div"),class:"webpages-header"},{webPageTarieven:document.createElement("a"),webPageReserveren:document.createElement("a"),webPageContact:document.createElement("a")},{webPagesLinks:["../../tarieven.html","../../reseveren.html","./contact.html",],webPagesText:["Tarieven","Reserveren","Contact"]}];

Object.keys(headerElements[4]).forEach((attr, i) => {
  headerElements[4][attr].setAttribute("href", headerElements[5].webPagesLinks[i]);
  headerElements[4][attr].textContent = headerElements[5].webPagesText[i];
});

console.log(headerElements[4]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could set the index with forEach as well. It makes the code cleaner too.